# Unable to handle responses using 'regex' http.status.code in Siddhi

Tags: siddhi

Unable to handle responses using, for response 500:

```
@source(type='http-response', sink.id = 'serviceActivate', http.status.code = '5\d+', @map(type = 'json', @attributes(result = '$.result')))
```

or

```
@source(type='http-response', sink.id = 'serviceActivate', http.status.code = '[2|4|5]00', @map(type = 'json', @attributes(result = '$.result')))
```

I see an error:

```
[2019-12-19 11:35:06,221] ERROR {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.http.source.HttpResponseMessageListener} - No source of type 'http-response' for status code '500' has been defined. Hence dropping the response message.
```

For multiple source consecutive, without using regexp, no error:

```
@source(.... http.status.code = '200',.....)
@source(.... http.status.code = '400',.....)
@source(.... http.status.code = '500',.....)
```

How do I write regexp correctly?

Comment: try this `http.status.code = '[245]00'`

Comment: Does not solve. The error remained,

Comment: What version of siddhi-io-http are you using?

Comment: WSO2 Carbon Kernel v5.2.7. WSO2sp 4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be due to the [bug](https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/issues/1051), WSO2 SP 4.4.0  is based on Siddhi core 4x and is currently not under active development. I tested the above with latest [Siddhi Distribution 5.1.2](https://github.com/siddhi-io/distribution/releases/tag/v5.1.2), could not reproduce.
See more details on siddhi 5x development [here](https://siddhi.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the regex for 200 and 400 ranged status with '2**' and '4**' respectively.