# Is there any plans for WSO2 SP 4.4.0 to upgrade siddhi core version to 5x?

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

[Unable to handle responses using 'regex' http.status.code in Siddhi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406540/unable-to-handle-responses-using-regex-http-status-code-in-siddhi)

In a reply to a question in the above-mentioned link you have said that "WSO2 SP 4.4.0 is based on Siddhi core 4x and is currently not under active development"

Is there any plans for WSO2 SP 4.4.0 to upgrade siddhi core version to 5x.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there's no plan to update Siddhi Core version in WSO2 SP v4.4.0. You can try out [WSO2 Streaming Integrator](https://wso2.com/integration/streaming-integrator/) or [Siddhi CNSP](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/download/) which is based on Siddhi 5xx. 
You can report for the bug WSO2 SP in https://github.com/wso2/product-sp repository or by dropping a mail to **dev@wso2.org**.

Furtheremore, I have added an answer to the previous question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59895095/8881500.